# Unable to install Final Fantasy 8 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, final-fantasy-8

I am trying to install FF8 on Win7 but I am having no luck.

The install disc opens a menu with an option to start the installation. I click on this and nothing happens. If I look in Task Manager I can see the SETUP.EXE running.

I have tried exploring the disc and running the SETUP.EXE directly, both normally and as administrator.

I am using .iso's and running on Win7 32-bit.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://forums.eyesonff.com/final-fantasy-viii/120909-how-run-final-fantasy-viii-pc-version-iso-real-way.html) will help?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I found that before I posted here and it only helps with running the game, not installing it.

Comment: OK, it was worth a try.. can you copy all the files to the hard disk and run it from there?

Comment: Have you tried running it in compatibility mode? or try running the installer from the command prompt?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I tried copying to disk but no luck.

Comment: @Krazer Also tried compatibility mode and running from command prompt. Still, no cookie.

Comment: Try running [Process Explorer](http://download.cnet.com/Process-Explorer/3000-2094_4-10223605.html) while the setup is active, right click its process and roam through its properties and threads.. maybe you'll bump into something that can shed some light on this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard When running Process Explorer I can see the SETUP.EXE process. When I open its properties and click on the Bring to Front button, it says 'No visible windows found for this process'. Could it be that my installer is corrupt or broken?

Comment: IF you can't get it installed, one option is to get a Playstation emulator and download a FF8 rom.

Comment: Silly question, but if nothing happens, have you tried running the installer as administrator?

Comment: @SaintWacko I had the emulator and I am not a big fan of it. That is the main reason I got the PC version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found a solution to the problem.

I created a directory on my hard drive and copied the .ISO files from my external drive to the directory I created.

I mounted the Install.iso and copied the files from there to the directory I created initially. I then ran the setup.exe in compatibility mode with the setting on Windows XP SP 2.

This worked fine and the game installed without any problems. I then followed the instructions given [here](http://forums.eyesonff.com/final-fantasy-viii/120909-how-run-final-fantasy-viii-pc-version-iso-real-way.html).

The game is running fine and I am yet to experience any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the urge to play this game again but I had the same problem. I lost many hours figuring it out but eventually I discovered that there was a conflict and Setup.exe was waiting on another process.

To find (and kill) whatever Setup.exe is waiting for:

1. Start Task Manager
2. Under the Performance tab, click the **Resource Monitor…** button
3. Find Setup.exe and right click it.
4. Select **Analyze Wait Chain…**
5. This will tell you which program is obstructing setup.exe from installing. Close that program and setup will run!

Answer (score -1):

when running the setup installation:
Go to task Manager, locate the setup.exe, right-click on raise the priority, setup should work now

Comment: That seems incredibly unlikely.

Comment: It does seem to correlate with another answer though.